# Magento 1.9.1 - Shopping cart price rules - Condition subselection issue

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, ce-1.9.1.0, bug, conditional-loading

After upgrade from Magento 1.8.1 to 1.9.1 I got not working add to cart button for configurable products, fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting! in /home/igor/vhosts/www/***/magento/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 625
```

Full exception [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GzkHUXix).

I found that issue occurred because of this rule:
 [image: rule]

Fix for this issue located at [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ihor-sviziev/1dfc3b546d86ea490d8f/revisions).

Would be great to add this fix in next release.

Answer (score 6):

The code fix was posted here too [Magento debug trace](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37395/magento-debug-trace/44112#44112)

**Note:-** the fix is not EE specific fix, it is just magento doesn't provide patches to non ee-users so that is why the person who answered it mentions a patch for EE but I have confirmed it works on CE also

See the part where it says

**Update 11/21/2014**

Magento just provided a patch for this as **PATCH_SUPEE-4814_EE_1.14.1.0_v1.sh** 
Changes are in: `app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Subselect.php` on line 114:

From:

```
if (parent::validate($item)) {
```

To:

```
if (Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine::validate($item)) {
```

Comment: I am using 1.14.2.3 and the code you mentioned isn't updated in this latest version. Maybe they fix the problem. Anyway, after upgrade I am getting Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in \lib\Varien\Object.php on line 344