# Fatal error when adding configurable product in cart and using "products subselection" in shopping cart price rules

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, shopping-cart-price-rules, fatal-error

I have this **products subselection** condition in a shoppng cart price rule:

If **ALL** of these conditions are **TRUE** :
If **total amount less than 16** for a subselection of items in cart matching **ALL** of these conditions:
Attribute Set **is Heft**

This works well except for configurable products. Once we add a configurable product into the cart we get this error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in [...]/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 629

And the configurable products don't even meet the conditions! (They are another attribute set.)

Why is this happening? Can any reproduce this problem? Any help is very much appreciated.

We use Magento CE 1.9.1 and memory limit is set to 512MB. I also tried 1024MB with the same outcome.

It worked in the previous version 1.6.

I also tried to debug Magento and ended up in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address at the function collectTotal. Because once I comment `$model->collect($this);` adding to cart works. (Of course not as expected, but the cart gets the product. Which wasn't the case before.)

Comment: Have you tried deactivating the rule to check if the issue is still present? You run out of memory because something really intensive is being executed on the add to cart action

Comment: What is your php memory limit set to?

Comment: @R.S An obvious solution but unfortunately the problem lies deeper in the system. My memory limit is 512MB. But I also tried with 1024MB. Same error it will just take little longer to fill up memory. :-) I will mention this in my question as this obviously leads to misunderstanding regarding my question as I'm looking for the root problem.

Comment: Can you add the code that causing this issue

Comment: @MayersDev Yes, deactivating the rule "deactivates" the error. I can also just change the condition and it works again. It's really just with this specific condition type.

Comment: @R.S I just added some code to my question. See last paragraph.

Comment: Any 3-d party extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile I found out it's a bug introduced in 1.9.1. There are already two issues in Magento's bug tracking tool about this (you need a Magento Account to see them)
http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/456
http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/567

While this does not solve my issue I know now it has nothing to do with my setup or any third party extensions. Therefore I rest my case and wait for the patch.

My current workaround is to convert any configurable product to a simple product. That is managable as we only have few. Otherwise I would have made a downgrade to 1.9.0. It is working there.

Comment: The following answer may solve your real problem: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/44112/142

Answer (score 6):

It's a problem with method aliasing in subclasses.

**tl;dr**

For version CE 1.9.1.0 you can try to patch `app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Combine.php` at line #219 turning

```
$valid = $children && $this->validate($children[0]);
```

into

```
$valid = $children && self::validate($children[0]);
```

For other versions, find the above line inside the `validate` method.

**Explanation**

`Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Subselect::validate()` overrides the `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine::validate()` and calls the parent implementation along the way. Too bad the latter eventually tries to call itself when met with rule validation on configurable products, but ends up calling the overriden implementation instead, so an infinite loop is started.

**Warning**

The quick fix proposed is consistent with the core `SalesRule` models but might break more complex class hyerarchies introduced by third party modules.

Comment: I used the latest app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Combine.php from Magento CE 1.9.3.4 which is fixing the problem as well