# Add to cart not working for configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, configurable-product, ce-1.9.1.0

Magento ver. 1.9.1.0, site is coolvape.co.uk

As far as I can tell all simple products will work fine however when a customer tries to add a configurable product to cart they just get a loading icon. I can't think of any changes that were made at the time it started occurring, it was working fine until a few days ago.
I've tried clearing the cache and reindexing.

If I disable Ajax for Add to Cart, you get directed to another url (e.g. /checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2Nvb2x2YXBlLmNvLnVrL2dlbmVyYWwtY3VzdGFyZC5odG1s/product/1650/form_key/OAXh9Lk7RduomSs5/) which doesn't load, saying Unable to load the web page because the server sent no data.

1650 is the ID of the cofigurable product, if I change it to an ID (e.g. 1653) of a simple product associated with that configurable product it will direct me to cart with that simple product added but no thumbnail and the text badly formatted.

[image: img]

Thanks

Comment: I suppose I can gaze into this crystal ball here and divinate the code changes that have taken place -- or, you know, you can copy + past the ajaxcart controller and  the javascript function that is dedicated  to it and we can all take a look.

Comment: can you enable logging and paste what happens adding a configurable products? it seems not a javascript issue, but a server side problem.

Comment: I also have this problem and the hosting company will analyse the problem next week as nothing is logged. It probably works if you disable certain shopping cart price rules though (the ones which do not need a coupon and use a products subselection). See [this related question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53699/fatal-error-when-adding-configurable-product-in-cart-and-using-products-subsele) (although they get an error message).

Comment: what's the url of the configurable product?

Comment: I would say you are getting a php error in your controller. Have you tried looking at the php logs to debug?

Comment: The following answer may solve your problem: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/44112/142